# TYPO3 with composer - Installing previous extension version

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I am trying to install the extension clickstorm seo for  TYPO3 9.5

But with the typical composer command "composer require clickstorm/cs_seo" I am only getting the latest version, which is for TYPO3 10.

Is there a way to get the previous version with the composer command?

Answer (score 3):

You can require a specific version just fine:

```
composer require clickstorm/cs_seo ^4.3
```

You can see the latest version compatible to TYPO3 by checking the [package site on Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/clickstorm/cs_seo#4.3.0).

Comment: Great thank you very much, I was missing the last part "^4.3"